# asp.net 4.0 c# Task.ContinueWith execution on UI thread not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, webforms, task

I have a web page that contains a button to do some time-consuming work (download some images in my case). In the button handler, I've created a task and attached a continuation task with it so that when the download ends I want to manipulate the UI.

The problem is that the UI never changes, although the task finishes correctly and the continuation task is reached.

Here's a part of the button handler code:

```
 var uiThreadScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
 Task t = new Task(DownloadImage, item, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
 t.ContinueWith((task) =>
 {
     ImageItem i = (ImageItem)task.AsyncState;
     lb_Success.Text = "Download done";// not working
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "MyScript", "alert('here');", true); // for test, also not working
 }, uiThreadScheduler);
 t.Start();
```

and here's DownloadImage:

```
private void DownloadImage(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            ImageItem item = (ImageItem)state;
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Proxy = null;
                var result = webClient.DownloadData(item.url);
                item.imageBytes = result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Errors.printError("Failed to download image");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you ensuring that the web response isn't sent before the task completes? Just changing the content of objects related to the page won't achieve anything if the response has already been sent to the client. If you're handling this somewhere else, that may be fine - but it would be good to put the detail into the question. It could be that what you *really* want is to send a response back to the client that includes Javascript to poll for the task being complete. The code for that would look *very* different though.

Comment: What I actually want is to display the images downloaded. I'm putting a breakpoint on the continuation part and its fired with all bytes and it's fine. The function DownloadImage simply contains a webclient with a synchronous DownloadData method so sure the task is done when web response is returned.

Comment: But you're not calling DownloadImage synchronously. You're starting it as a background task... so I strongly suspect you *are* returning the response to the client before that finishes.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I've added DownloadImage  function

Comment: Think about the timing of what happens. I *suspect* it's: 1) You start DownloadImage in a separate task. 2) You send your response to the web browser, because you're not waiting for that task to complete. 3) The task completes. 4) The continuation executes, modifying an in-memory representation of the web page - but all of this is after the response has already been sent to the browser.